# Using PATCH/PUT rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, curl

While running a curl and using PATCH or PUT, I receive a 204 message, but the record is not updating.

**cURL**

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Token token="tWJ3nqnNx6yxzC6pkWyo"' -X PUT http://localhost:4000/api/v1/miboxes/186 -d '{"mibox":{"tag_list":["fred", "mouse", "love"]}}'
```

**API Controller**

```
  def update
    respond_with Mibox.update(params[:id], params[:miboxes])
  end
```

**Controller**

```
# PATCH/PUT /myboxes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /myboxes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @mibox.update(mibox_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @mibox, notice: 'Mibox was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @mibox.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if its the rails way, but I replaced

respond_with Mibox.update(params[:id], params[:miboxes])

with

respond_with Mibox.update(params[:id], mibox_params)

and it started to work.

Comment: It is because you are using strong paramaters